# Logout all users with sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sorcery

I need to logout all user in my rails application that uses sorcery. I tried running the code below in rails console but it says logout is undefined.

```
User.all.each { |user| logout user}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your doing this in your console and `logout` is undefined then you need to `require 'sorcery'` before you can use it's methods.

```
require 'sorcery'
User.all.each { |user| logout user}
```

Comment: it returns false when I try to require sorcery

Comment: that's expected. It almost always says that. did the method work though